# Easiest to set up local webserver for Windows

Tags: windows, webserver

I love POW for Mac, what's the most similar solution for Windows?

The easiest way on a Windows pc to put a local webserver running for website testing/developing?

Thanks!

Comment: What environment do you need to develop for? Or more specifically which language? For PHP and Perl you might want to go with WAMPP if ASP then use IIS.

Comment: Control Panel->Program & Features->Add Windows Components->Internet Information Server

Comment: https://github.com/75lb/local-web-server

Comment: The [WT-NMP](http://wtriple.com/wtnmp/) stack

Comment: Also see how to set up node.js http server here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16333790/node-js-quick-file-server-static-files-over-http

Answer (score 3):

It depends on which programming language/platform you'd like to start with.
The most easiest way would be using the windows integrated IIS.

1. Windows XP/2000. Click Start then Run, type **inetmgr.exe** and press enter. you'll have iis window opened. If not, you need install this feature by default.
2. Windows 7/Server 2008. Click Start then Run, type **optionalfeatures** and press enter. Check "Internet Information Services" in the popped up window and click OK to "enable" this feature.

[image: enable IIS]

Please refer [ASP.net](http://www.asp.net) for more information to host a website with IIS.

If you don't like C#/VB.net etc. You still can download and install [Apache Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi) in windows to use Java, PHP and other language.

Comment: Thanks man. I've been using xampp. Sorry for the late reply.